# NodeJS Passport Custom Callback on Local Strategy doesn't trigger serialize/deserialize functions

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to get Passport working with a custom callback on a local strategy. 
I am using AngularJS in the frontend and nodejs, express on the backend.
So far I have been able to get the whole workflow done. My problem is that apparently the strategy does not invoke the deserialize / serialize functions in the verify callback when using custom callbacks. The curious thing is when I let passport handle the rest without giving a custom callback the functions are being called and I got 'foo' or 'bar' printed in the console.
Or maybe I just missed something important, but I cannot find anything in the docs or from other sources which could fix my problem.

```
      var sessionOpts = {
        saveUninitialized: true, // saved new sessions
        resave: false, // do not automatically write to the session store
        store: sessionStore,
        secret: sessionSecret,
        cookie : { httpOnly: true, maxAge: config.session.maxAge } // configure when sessions expires
      };

        var server = express();

      // log all requests to the console
      server.use(morgan('dev'));
      server.use(bodyParser.json());
      server.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: true
      }));
      server.use(session(sessionOpts));
      server.use(passport.initialize());
      server.use(passport.session());  


  // used to serialize the user for the session
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    console.log('foo')
    var sessionUser = {
      id: user._id,
      email: user.email
    };
    done(null, sessionUser)
  });

  // used to deserialize the user
  passport.deserializeUser(function(sessionUser, done) {
    console.log('bar')
    done(null, sessionUser);
  });

passport.use('local-signin', new LocalStrategy({
      // by default, local strategy uses username and password, we will override with email
      usernameField: 'email',
      passwordField: 'password',
      passReqToCallback: true // allows us to pass back the entire request to the callback
    },
    function (req, email, password, done) { // callback with email and password from our form
      // attempt to authenticate user
      User.getAuthenticated(email, password, function (err, user, reason) {
        if (err) return done(err);

        // login was successful if we have a user
        if (user) {
          // handle login success
          return done(null, user);
        }

        // otherwise send back the reason why it failed
        return done(null, false, reason)
      });

    }));
```

And this is my route defined in express (error handling are just dummy error codes for now):

```
server.get('/signin', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-signin', function(err, user, reason) {
      if (err) {
        return res.sendStatus(500);
      }

      // login was successful if we have a user
      if (user) {
        // handle login success
        return res.send(user);
      }

      // otherwise we can determine why we failed
      var reasons = User.failedLogin;

      switch (reason) {
        case reasons.NOT_FOUND:
          return res.sendStatus(401);
          break;
        case reasons.PASSWORD_INCORRECT:
          // note: these cases are usually treated the same - don't tell
          // the user *why* the login failed, only that it did
          return res.sendStatus(402);
          break;
        case reasons.MAX_ATTEMPTS:
          // send email or otherwise notify user that account is
          // temporarily locked
          return res.sendStatus(403);
          break;
        default:
          return res.sendStatus(500)
      }

    })(req, res, next);
  });
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

After searching the internet for about 2 days with absolutely no result or any example which could help me with my problem I posted the question here. Now right after posting it I found the solution in the docs. How embarrassing...
The solution is in this sentence: **"Note that when using a custom callback, it becomes the application's responsibility to establish a session (by calling req.login()) and send a response."**
Whatever... I hope this helps someone else to save some time
edited code from above:

```
server.get('/signin', function(req, res, next) {
    passport.authenticate('local-signin', function(err, user, reason) {
      if (err) {
        return res.sendStatus(500);
      }

      // login was successful if we have a user
      if (user) {
        // handle login success
        return req.login(user, function(err) {
          if (err) return res.sendStatus(500);

          return res.send(user)
        });
      }

      // otherwise we can determine why we failed
```